# Visual Studio 2010 (Not Responding) when I "Go to definition"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've been having this problem for about a week now where Visual Studio 2010 Premium SP1Rel will freeze and become completely unresponsive sometimes when I'm opening a file with Solution Explorer or if I push F12 to "Go to definition".

I only have DevExpress Tools, Ghost Doc, and Productivity Power Tools installed for extensions, and I'm using sourcegear vault for source control.

I've watched the process in Task Manager after it becomes unresponsive and the RAM usage slowly climbs by about 400k before immediately dropping back to where it was, or a little bit higher. It keeps doing this over and over and I've let the memory used by it get as high as 1,300,000 KB over about 10 minutes, waiting to see if it would ever come back.

This behavior is only happening on this specific ASP.NET solution that I'm currently developing. The total size of all the files is about 127 MB if that tells you anything about how big the solution is.

The behavior started after trying to add a test project to the solution. I tried to use the right-click  -> Create Unit Test on a method in the solution and it is then that it froze for the first time. It looked like it froze while trying to add this file to the solution.

I force closed VS and re-opened the solution and tried to open the file and it immediately froze again. After that I tried again and it ended up opening the file, but now it will freeze up randomly while I'm opening other files.

Has anyone dealt with something like this before in Visual Studio? How did you fix it? Would you have any recommendations on what I should try? Is there any other information you need me to get?